# What IP address(es) can't be bound to a listening socket?

Tags: socket, ip-address

What IP address(es) can't be bound to a listening socket?

For example, can a server process bind 255.255.255.255 to a listening socket?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm... Not sure what you mean. I'm also not sure *you* know what you mean here...

Comment: should you not be asking which IP addresses are valid addresses before you ask if you can bind a socket to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Linux `bind(2)` man page:

> It is normally necessary to assign a local address using bind()  before a SOCK_STREAM socket may receive connections (see accept(2)).
>
> The  rules used in name binding vary between address families.  Consult the manual entries in Section 7 for detailed information.  For AF_INET, see ip(7); for AF_INET6, see ipv6(7); for AF_UNIX, see unix(7); for AF_APPLETALK, see ddp(7); for AF_PACKET, see packet(7); for AF_X25, see x25(7); and for AF_NETLINK, see netlink(7).

And for IPv4, the `ip(7)` man page says:

> When a process wants to receive new incoming packets or connections, it should bind a socket to a local interface address using bind(2).   In this case, only one IP socket may be bound to any given local (address, port) pair.  When INADDR_ANY is specified in the bind call, the socket will be bound to all local interfaces. When listen(2) is called on an unbound socket, the socket is automatically bound to a random free port with the local address set to INADDR_ANY.

So it would seem that for IPv4 TCP or UDP sockets, the IP to bind must be either `INADDR_ANY` or one of the IP addresses assigned to any of the network interfaces on the local system.

But it also says:

> There are several special addresses: INADDR_LOOPBACK (127.0.0.1) always refers to the local host via the loopback device; INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) means any address for binding; INADDR_BROADCAST (255.255.255.255) means any host and has the same effect on bind as INADDR_ANY for historical reasons.

So, binding to 255.255.255.255 is valid and has the same effect of 0.0.0.0, but in modern implementations 0.0.0.0 is the preferred one.

And if you set the `IP_FREEBIND` socket option, you can bind to any address, in the assumption that the bound-to address may appear on some local interface at a later time. Until that actually happens, though, a socket bound in such a way may not be very useful.

Linux also has a `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option which can be used to bind a socket to a specific network interface without specifying its IP address.

Comment: IP_FREEBIND it also mentions this. So, it seems that any IP can be bind

Comment: You said "a socket bound in such a way may not be very useful". What if a packet with this address as destination actually arrive at your machine? Will it be directly dropped because non of your network interface  is assigned with such address?

Comment: Since the interface won't be sending ARP replies for an address that hasn't been configured yet, I think having the packet actually arrive would require something out of ordinary at the Ethernet layer, like the packet being sent as Ethernet broadcast with a non-broadcast IP address, or having the MAC address of the recipient host being manually configured with the ARP table of the L2 sender *and* possibly to the local switch(es) too.